What proof do I need to present in France that I am disabled?
What proof is acceptable in France that I am disabled?  I have had both of my hips replaced TWICE! I am 77. I have nerve damage in my right leg. I have a drop right foot. I wear a brace on my right foot to hold my right foot in the proper position and walk with a cane. I have weak legs and have a fused back for L2-L4

For what purpose do you want to establish in France that you are disabled?  Parking spaces?  Something else?

Could you explain how this is related to travel?

Does this answer your question? What proof of disability is accepted in France?

A precision of your country of origin should help. With likely big differences if you came from eu or outside (the french 'proof' of disabilities are valid in all EU, it would make sense to be the same in the other way)
